# How to upload multiple datasets and output a table of each dataframe in Dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a simple dash app where a user can upload a dataset and the app outputs the dataset in a table.

I want the user to be able to upload multiple datasets and the table of each of these datasets to be shown.

So for example, if the user was to upload three different datasets than the dash app would show a table of the first dataset to be uploaded, followed by a table of the second dataset to be uploaded, followed by a table of the third dataset to be uploaded.

How can I do this? Here is my current code:

```
import base64
import datetime
import io
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import dcc, html, dash_table
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
server = app.server

colors = {"graphBackground": "#F5F5F5", "background": "#ffffff", "text": "#000000"}

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Upload(
            id="upload-data",
            children=html.Div(["Drag and Drop or ", html.A("Select Files")]),
            multiple=True,
        ),
        html.Div(id="output-data-upload"),
    ]
)

def parse_data(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(",")

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if "csv" in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV or TXT file
            df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode("utf-8")))
        elif "xls" in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        elif "txt" or "tsv" in filename:
            # Assume that the user upl, delimiter = r'\s+'oaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode("utf-8")), delimiter=r"\s+")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div(["There was an error processing this file."])

    return df

@app.callback(
    Output("output-data-upload", "children"),
    [Input("upload-data", "contents"), Input("upload-data", "filename")],
)
def update_table(contents, filename):
    table = html.Div()

    if contents:
        contents = contents[0]
        filename = filename[0]
        df = parse_data(contents, filename)

        table = html.Div(
            [
                html.H5(filename),
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    data=df.to_dict("rows"),
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                ),
                html.Hr(),
                html.Div("Raw Content"),
                html.Pre(
                    contents[0:200] + "...",
                    style={"whiteSpace": "pre-wrap", "wordBreak": "break-all"},
                ),
            ]
        )

    return table


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `update_table` callback, you would need to *append* the newly created table to the *list* of `children` in the output div rather than returning the new table (which would just reset the list with only that table).

Since Dash 2.9, we can make [partial property updates](https://dash.plotly.com/partial-properties) using the `Patch` class :

```py
@app.callback(
    Output("output-data-upload", "children"),
    [Input("upload-data", "contents"), Input("upload-data", "filename")],
)
def update_table(contents, filename):
    patched_children = Patch()

    if contents:
        contents = contents[0]
        filename = filename[0]
        df = parse_data(contents, filename)

        table = html.Div(
            [
                html.H5(filename),
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    data=df.to_dict("records"),
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                ),
                html.Hr(),
                html.Div("Raw Content"),
                html.Pre(
                    contents[0:200] + "...",
                    style={"whiteSpace": "pre-wrap", "wordBreak": "break-all"},
                ),
            ]
        )

        patched_children.append(table)

    return patched_children
```

Note also that `data=df.to_dict("rows")` is not valid (`orient='rows'` does not exist), you probably meant `data=df.to_dict("records")`.

Comment: How can I do this with graphs? So that for every dataset the user uploads, the app outputs another graph. I tried using the same code format as above and got 'cannot patch undefined'

Comment: Hard to tell without the code, but the principle should remain the same. If the documentation doesn't help, feel free to ask another question with all the details, I will have a look.

Comment: I'm still stuck, so I made another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946004/how-to-upload-multiple-datasets-and-output-a-graph-of-each-dataframe-in-dash