# How to upload multiple datasets and output a graph of each dataframe in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a simple dash app where a user can upload a dataset and the app outputs a simple scatterplot of the first column versus the second column (therefore only data with continuous values in the first/second column will work)

I want the user to be able to upload multiple datasets and the graph of each of these datasets to be shown.

So for example, if the user was to upload three different datasets than the dash app would show a graph of the first dataset to be uploaded, followed by a graph of the second dataset to be uploaded, followed by a graph of the third dataset to be uploaded.

How can I do this? Here is my current code:

```
import base64
import datetime
import io
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import dcc, html, dash_table, Patch
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
server = app.server

colors = {"graphBackground": "#F5F5F5", "background": "#ffffff", "text": "#000000"}

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Upload(
            id="upload-data",
            children=html.Div(["Drag and Drop or ", html.A("Select Files")]),
            multiple=True,
        ),
        html.Div(id="graph1"),
    ]
)

def parse_data(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(",")

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if "csv" in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV or TXT file
            df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode("utf-8")))
        elif "xls" in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        elif "txt" or "tsv" in filename:
            # Assume that the user upl, delimiter = r'\s+'oaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode("utf-8")), delimiter=r"\s+")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div(["There was an error processing this file."])

    return df

@app.callback(
    Output("graph1", "figure"),
    [Input("upload-data", "contents"), Input("upload-data", "filename")],
)
def update_table(contents, filename):
    patched_children = Patch()

    if contents:
        contents = contents[0]
        filename = filename[0]
        df = parse_data(contents, filename)

        Fig = html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Graph(go.Figure(
        data=[
            go.Scatter(
                mode="markers", 
                x=df.iloc[:,0], 
                y=df.iloc[:,1],

                showlegend=False

                    )
               
            ],
        layout=go.Layout(
            width=500,
            height=500,
            plot_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"],
            paper_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"]
        )))
            ]
        )

        patched_children.append(Fig)

    return patched_children

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a patch is applied to its corresponding `Output` component.

The first issue is the output of the second callback : you want to add a graph to this output (hence "patch" it) each time data are uploaded, so you need to target the `children` property of the container div (not `figure`), just like with the tables in your previous question, so that you can append (or prepend) the newly created graph to the graph list.

To prevent confusion you could first rename the container div id to `'graph-container'` instead of `'graph1'` :

```py
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Upload(
            id="upload-data",
            children=html.Div(["Drag and Drop or ", html.A("Select Files")]),
            multiple=True,
        ),
        html.Div(id='graph-container')
    ]
)
```

Then you can fix the callback output as follows :

```py
@app.callback(
    Output("graph-container", "children"),
    [Input("upload-data", "contents"), Input("upload-data", "filename")],
)
def update_table(contents, filename):
    # ...
```

---

The second issue is how you build the graph in the callback :

```py
dcc.Graph(go.Figure(...))        # error
```

This will throw an error because the first positional argument of `dcc.Graph()` is a placeholder for the component `id`, not `figure`. So you need to pass the figure as a keyword argument and remember that in general "*explicit is better than implicit*" :

```py
dcc.Graph(figure=go.Figure(...)) # ok
```

---

I couldn't reproduce the error you mentioned in the comment so here is the full code I came up with, which works fine :

```py
external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
server = app.server

colors = {"graphBackground": "#F5F5F5", "background": "#ffffff", "text": "#000000"}

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Upload(
            id="upload-data",
            children=html.Div(["Drag and Drop or ", html.A("Select Files")]),
            multiple=True,
        ),
        html.Div(id='graph-container'),
    ]
)

def parse_data(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(",")

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if "csv" in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV or TXT file
            df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode("utf-8")))
        elif "xls" in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        elif "txt" or "tsv" in filename:
            # Assume that the user upl, delimiter = r'\s+'oaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode("utf-8")), delimiter=r"\s+")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div(["There was an error processing this file."])

    return df

@app.callback(
    Output("graph-container", "children"),
    [Input("upload-data", "contents"), Input("upload-data", "filename")],
)
def update_table(contents, filename):
    patched_children = Patch()

    if contents:
        contents = contents[0]
        filename = filename[0]
        df = parse_data(contents, filename)

        fig = go.Figure(
            data=go.Scatter(
                mode="markers",
                x=df.iloc[:,0],
                y=df.iloc[:,1],
                showlegend=False),
            layout=go.Layout(
                width=500,
                height=500,
                plot_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"],
                paper_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"])
        )

        graph = dcc.Graph(figure=fig)

        patched_children.append(graph)

    return patched_children

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I only changed the output line from what I had previously to 'Output("graph-container", "children")' and I get the  error message 'An object was provided as `children` instead of a component, string, or number (or list of those)'

Comment: @Niam45 I couldn't reproduce that error specifically but I landed on another one, see my revised answer. Note that if you still have errors running the full code I provided, it's likely that you are running an outdated version of Dash. Your feedback is welcome.